# Javascript code printing multiple results

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some code that will print either "Spinning left" or "Spinning right" depending on whether the left or right arrow keys are pressed down. At the moment, it seems to continuously print out the statement until the other key is pressed, and then it will just print the other statement many times instead. Heres my code at the moment :

```
   function Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            print("spinning left");
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
            print("Spinning right");
        }
    }
```

I originally had "left" instead of KeyCode.LeftArrow, but it didn't change the output. I'm new to Javascript, so is there something that I forgot to do to make the program stop registering that the button is pushed?

Comment: WHen and how do you call Update()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess he's working in Unity...

use if (**Input.GetKeyDown ("left")**) instead of **KeyCode.LeftArrow**

this only prints if you hold down the key...

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: Changed it to this, but it still seems to be printing out the statements a random number of times, but this could be due to a delay in me hitting the button and then letting it go. It stops now when I release the key, so thanks for helping

Comment: maybe your scene is just to demanding for your system (web player)?

Comment: Could be, but I've replaced the statements with what I want the object to do(rotate in the direction pressed), and it works how I want it to now. Might come back to this part later if it starts acting up again